# How to get root folder name of imagepath in txt file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a question in C++ about get name that seperated by "\". I have a text file that store full path of image and its labels (just 1,2...) such as

```
Image_align\Russian\1.jpg;1
Image_align\USA\2.jpg;1
Image_align\China\3.jpg;2
```

I want to get the image name and its root folder name. For example. I have image '1.jpg' and its root folder is 'Russia'. I do something and I done to get the file name. Now, I remain its root folder. Could you have me to find it by C++? Thank in advance

This is my code that I tried

```
std::ifstream
file("database.txt");
char separator = ';'; //Filename and label separate by ";"
string imagepath; //'Image_align\Russian\1.jpg'
string label;
while (std::getline(file, content))
{
stringstream liness(content);
getline(liness, imagepath, separator);
Mat image = imread(imagepath);
const size_t last_slash_idx = imagepath.find_last_of("\\/");
if (std::string::npos != last_slash_idx)
{
    imagepath.erase(0, last_slash_idx + 1);
}
string imagename=imagepath;
//Now I want to get the its root folder such as 'Russia', 'USA'..
```

Comment: Why not use the POSIX functions basename and dirname?

Comment: @stark I have no expert in that code. Hence, I just parse the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pitching a slightly smarter tokenizer

```
void multiparse(string overtoken, vector<string> &tokens, const char * delims)
{
    stringstream ss(overtoken);
    string token;
    while (getline(ss, token, delims[0]))
    {
        if (delims[1] == '\0' || token.length() == 0)
        {
            tokens.push_back(token);
        }
        else
        {
            multiparse(token, tokens, &delims[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
while (std::getline(file, content))
{
    stringstream liness(content);
    getline(liness, imagepath, separator);
    Mat image = imread(imagepath);
    vector<string> tokens;
    multiparse(imagepath, tokens, "/\\");
    string imagename;
    string rootfolder;
    if (tokens.size() >= 2)
    {     
        vector<string>::iterator it = tokens.end();
        --it;
        imagename = *it;
        --it;
        rootfolder = *it;
        // do stuff
    }
    else
    {  
        cerr << "Parsed bad line" << endl;
        // appropriate failure response
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your project can use Win32 API, [PathRemoveFileSpec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773748(v=vs.85).aspx) should be a way to go.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it does not work  char *cstr= new char[imagepath.length() + 1];
    strcpy(cstr, imagepath.c_str());
 PathRemoveFileSpec(cstr);